# Can't get installation menu of Kubuntu, while Ubuntu's menu is loaded just fine

Tags: system-installation, usb, kubuntu

1. I'm trying to install the latest Kubuntu, the `Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` from https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/
2. I've tried to d/l with `http` protocol and `torrent`, getting the same `sha256`.
3. I've tried to make bootable USB stick with `USBImager`, `Etcher` and `rufus` with multiple setting combinations, including the suggested settings in official ubuntu tutorial here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#5-write-the-iso
4. I have UEFI enables, secure boot disabled and SATA set to AHCI
5. I tried(as of today, on the same machine etc) to d/l and create bootable USB stick and successfully loading the initial installation setup menu with `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`
6. Yet, with all the above present, I can't get into the fricking kubuntu installation setup menu... It doesn't see it.

My machine is xps 13(not the newset)

Comment: I have a separate folder with all my ISOs. And then always use zsync to update daily or convert last daily to final. Even used it to change Ubuntu ISO to Kubuntu although almost same as downloading entire ISO. Zsync also verifies download. From folder with ISO. `zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/22.04.1/release/kubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync` If changing version, I copy ISO & rename to what I want to download. I then directly boot ISO using grub2' loopmount. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: @oldfred I really appreciate when people share their best practices with others, despite it doesn't directly relate to the subject(this is **not** sarcasm). That been said, I don't see, unfortunately, how this could solve my problem. The ISOs I've d/l passed the sha256 sum, it's clearly something with Kubuntu, I can't see another way. I'm currently updating my BIOS and will try to install again, but I'm kind of pessimistic about it. Don't really know what to do with that, because installing Ubuntu and the uninstalling gnome can be messy.

Comment: Dell typically needs UEFI updates & some UEFI settings and then just work. I have Ubuntu on old Dell & new Dell, but not XPS versions. And I totally converted to Kubuntu several years ago. What video chip? And what version XPS?

Comment: @oldfred Yes, I can understand that, but the fact that I was able to install Ubuntu just fine while Kubuntu not so much didn't seem logical. Thanks for trying to help, oldfred.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to lie, in moments like this, I feel super-ultra-highly-skilled MF.

So, the solution is kind of simple, even though it was the first time I had to do this: I've manually created new boot option (`BIOS > Boot sequence > Add boot option`) with file in the `EFI > boot > grubx64.efi`.

The only thing that surprise me so far is the fact that this is LTS version and it was released 12 aug 2022 (https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-22-04-1-lts-update-available/) and yet, I'm the only one facing this bug. Am I really the only one experienced this.

Comment: Is this an HP? They only seem to recognized boot changes in HP's UEFI settings not from installers use of efibootmgr when installing grub.

Comment: @oldfred No, this is an 2020 model of Dell XPS 13